# Empty body Using Prerender.io with Meteor

Tags: meteor, prerender

I try to use prerender.io with a Meteor 1.5 App. I use the npm prerender-node package

```
  var prerenderio = Npm.require('prerender-node') .set('prerenderToken', token)
                                                .set('protocol', protocol)
                                                .set('host', host);  


  // Feed it to middleware! (app.use)
  WebApp.connectHandlers.use(prerenderio);
```

I seed log in prerender.io with code 200. Paged are cached but pages only contain the head and an empty body.

To make tests, I added the package meteorhacks:inject-initial and inserted lines in the body and it works fine. 
I wonder if I have a problem with the router that is flowrouter.

I also place

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="fragment" content="!">
  ALL  <meta ... >
  <!-- a script -->
  <scripts ... >
  <!-- prerenderio -->
  <script> console.log(Date()); window.prerenderReady = false; </script>  
</head>
```

To test, I flushed the cache of prerender.io.
when I test https://www.toto.com?_escaped_fragment_=

I don't have any time in the client console. I see the new line on prerender.io

I did the same test into 
https://www.bing.com/webmaster/diagnostics/seo/analyzer

Now let's see the new cache line content:

```
  Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
  Date: Wed, 21 Jun 2017 20:16:33 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: close
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Content-Encoding: gzip


  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteorhacks_zones/assets/utils.js?1498075872540"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteorhacks_zones/assets/before.js?1498075872540"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteorhacks_zones/assets/zone.js?1498075872540"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteorhacks_zones/assets/tracer.js?1498075872540"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteorhacks_zones/assets/after.js?1498075872540"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteorhacks_zones/assets/reporters.js?1498075872540"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="__meteor-css__" href="/f6675d95a01ce3ac63036505eb1ace94a68b1bb7.css?meteor_css_resource=true">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Toto</title>

    ...

    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">

    ...

    <!-- http referrer links -->
    <meta name="referrer" content="always">


    <meta name="fragment" content="!">



    <!-- No resize on mobiles -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"> <!--320-->

    <!-- a script -->
    <script ... ></script>

    <!-- prerenderio -->
    <script> console.log(Date()); window.prerenderReady = false; </script>

  </head>
  <body>



  <script type="text/javascript">__meteor_runtime_config__ = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent("%7B%22meteorRelease%22%3A%22METEOR%401.5-beta.8%22%2C%22meteorEnv%22%3A%7B%22NODE_ENV%22%3A%22production%22%2C%22TEST_METADATA%22%3A%22%7B%7D%22%7D%2C%22PUBLIC_SETTINGS%22%3A%7B%22analyticsSettings%22%3A%7B%22autorun%22%3Afalse%2C%22Mixpanel%22%3A%7B%22token%22%3A%225fc6f49885cbf2ec8d80a15c0a310399%22%2C%22people%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22Google%20Analytics%22%3A%7B%22trackingId%22%3A%22UA-60492530-2%22%7D%7D%2C%22ga%22%3A%7B%22account%22%3A%22UA-60492530-2%22%7D%7D%2C%22ROOT_URL%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.Toto.com%22%2C%22ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX%22%3A%22%22%2C%22appId%22%3A%221yyz6nr2dyysy1rxvng3%22%2C%22autoupdateVersion%22%3A%2237dc9ce25f5e0f5f3a2253bdcb3c80166a4e83d2%22%2C%22autoupdateVersionRefreshable%22%3A%2273bc2363ca210840ec3d6947a649e3388beca5c5%22%2C%22autoupdateVersionCordova%22%3A%224b9074136556412500d12284625a4f5d81ac3f3d%22%7D"));</script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fef4959b1bc37d5a9c2a1c09ddcb28fd7c374f10.js?meteor_js_resource=true"></script>


  </body>
  </html>
```

Here I gave the entire body content. I didn't remove any line.

Comment: I think Meteor 1.5 might use some ES6 code, which our PhantomJS v2.1.1 browser can't handle :( We are working on switching to Headless Chrome but can't give an ETA there. If you are able to switch to Meteor 1.4 in the meantime then that should fix it. Sorry for the trouble :(

Comment: I see. I can't get back to Meteor 1.4 due to some other features. We took abvantage of the all the benefits of 1.5.

Comment: Can you send me an email at todd@prerender.io? I'll see what we can do with getting you on Chrome as soon as we can get something ready.

Comment: Looks like you're using ES6, and Phantom used by prerender.io can't handle it. You may be interested to try [this service with support of ES6](https://ostr.io/info/prerendering), or make sure there is no ES6 code in your app's bundle.

Comment: Awesome! I did the install in the morning. Just a couple of minutes and it works. I wonder if I still need the <script> window.prerenderReady = false; </script>

Comment: @MarcRoche there is `window.IS_RENDERED` is used, see [docs here](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/spiderable-middleware#speed-up-rendering)

Comment: @MarcRoche, i am having the same issue, how did you manage to fix the issue ? i am using meteor METEOR@1.6.0.1 . Please let me know if you had to change something ?

Answer (score 0):

Prerender user here.  We had issues with Prerender not waiting until all scripts ran to completion and therefore the calculated dom is not yet fully rendered which sounds like what you're encountering.  We solved this by using the prerender ready flag described in the prerender documentation copied here for convenience:

Put this in your HTML:

```
<script> window.prerenderReady = false; </script>
```

When we see window.prerenderReady set to false, we'll wait until it's set to true to save the HTML. Execute the following when your page will be ready (usually after ajax calls).

```
window.prerenderReady = true;
```

Comment: I forgot to say that I put this in the main.html <head> and I also put another one with inject. I added a console.log to check that both are executed.

Comment: Are you sure that you're setting the `window.prerenderReady = true;` after all the data is loaded and the view is completely rendered?